# How to subtract times in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe which has time in hours:minutes format (e.g. 09:35) and I would like to get the difference between consequtive times in the B column with reference to their associated keys in the A column.

The data look like this:

```
      A        B
1     key1     09:12
2     key1     09:15
3     key1     09:21
4     key2     10:21
5     key2     10:27
6     key2     10:32
```

The output should be something like this:

```
      A        B
1     key1     00:00
2     key1     00:03
3     key1     00:06
4     key2     00:00
5     key2     00:06
6     key2     00:05
```

Or something like this:

```
      A        B
1     key1     0
2     key1     3
3     key1     6
4     key2     0
5     key2     6
6     key2     5
```

I know in case the data in B column are integers, we can do something like this:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

However, the data in B column are not integers, but in time format.

Any help in solving this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

***plan***

- use `pd.to_datetime` to convert `%H:%M` format to `Timestamp`s.  Yes, the dates will be incorrect.  But that won't matter once we use `diff`
- `groupby` column `'A'` and use `diff` to turn into `Timedelta`s
- use `pd.to_datetime` again, so we can use `dt.strftime` and format back to `'%H:%M'`

---

```
pd.to_datetime(df.B).groupby(df.A).diff().fillna(0)

1   00:00:00
2   00:03:00
3   00:06:00
4   00:00:00
5   00:06:00
6   00:05:00
Name: B, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

```
pd.to_datetime(
    pd.to_datetime(df.B).groupby(df.A).diff().fillna(0)
).dt.strftime('%H:%M')

1    00:00
2    00:03
3    00:06
4    00:00
5    00:06
6    00:05
Name: B, dtype: object
```

---

```
pd.to_datetime(df.B) \
    .groupby(df.A).diff() \
    .fillna(0).dt.total_seconds() \
    .div(60).astype(int)

1    0
2    3
3    6
4    0
5    6
6    5
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, you did not take into account the A column.